"Flowing" JToolBar
Here's my goal: to make a toolbar with buttons that "flow" down once the window is shrunk far enough. It should not be shy about nudging the sibling below if necessary
How do I do it?
Here's a demo. I addressed some criticisms of my previous questions about using external libraries so none are used here
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FlowToolbarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flow Toolbar Demo");
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Click to see action");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        labelPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JToolBar toolbar = new JToolBar();
        LayoutManager toolbarLayout = new FlowLayout();
        toolbar.setLayout(toolbarLayout);
        JButton heartButton = getHeartButton(e -> label.setText("Heart action performed..."));
        JButton starButton = getStarButton(e -> label.setText("Star action performed..."));
        toolbar.add(heartButton);
        toolbar.add(starButton);

        LayoutManager headerPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel headerPanel = new JPanel(headerPanelLayout);
        headerPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        headerPanel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel businessPanel = getBusinessPanel();

        LayoutManager mainPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(businessPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static JPanel getBusinessPanel() {
        LayoutManager businessPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel businessPanel = new JPanel(businessPanelLayout);
        JTable tableOne = getTableOne();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneOne = new JScrollPane(tableOne);
        scrollPaneOne.setOpaque(true);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Business Table One", scrollPaneOne);
        JTable tableTwo = getTableTwo();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneTwo = new JScrollPane(tableTwo);
        scrollPaneTwo.setOpaque(true);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Business Table Two", scrollPaneTwo);
        businessPanel.add(tabbedPane);
        return businessPanel;
    }

    private static JTable getTableOne() {
        Object[][] data = {
                {"John Doe", 30, "Male"},
                {"Jane Smith", 25, "Female"},
                {"Alice Johnson", 35, "Female"}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "Gender"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        return new JTable(model);
    }

    private static JTable getTableTwo() {
        Object[][] data = {
                {"Apple", 30, true},
                {"Orange", 25, true},
                {"Ackee fruit", 35, false}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Fruit", "Quantity", "Is Edible"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        return new JTable(model);
    }

    private static JButton getHeartButton(ActionListener heartAction) throws IOException {
        return getButton("Do Heart action", "heart.png", heartAction);
    }
    private static JButton getStarButton(ActionListener starAction) throws IOException {
        return getButton("Do Star action", "star.png", starAction);
    }
    
    private static JButton getButton(String buttonText, String resourceName, ActionListener actionListener) throws IOException {
        URL imageLocation = FlowToolbarDemo.class.getResource(resourceName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(imageLocation, "Requested resource not found"));
        Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonText, icon);
        button.addActionListener(actionListener);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        return button;
    }
}

heart.png

star.png

The buttons do flow, but they flow below the allocated area for the north component and become mostly invisible. JTabbedPane pane titles, on the other hand, flow smoothly. I included it in part to show what type of "flowing" I'm trying to achieve with my toolbar buttons


BorderLayout is chosen for the main panel since it's known for respecting the preferred height of its north components (which is in this case the header panel). However, as I discovered with the IntelliJ Debugger, the header panel's preferred height doesn't change even after the buttons stack. It's because the preferred height of the toolbar doesn't change. If it did, we would get something like this

It's technically achievable with an ugly kludge like this one
        toolbar.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Component firstButton = toolbar.getComponent(0);
                double firstButtonY = firstButton.getLocation().getY();
                Component secondButton = toolbar.getComponent(1);
                double secondButtonY = secondButton.getLocation().getY();
                if (firstButtonY < secondButtonY) {
                    int newHeight = (int) ((firstButton.getHeight() + secondButton.getHeight()) * 1.25);
                    toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, newHeight));
                } else if (firstButtonY == firstButtonY) {
                    int oldHeight = (int) (firstButton.getHeight() * 1.25);
                    toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, oldHeight));
                }
            }
        });

but obviously I'm not willing to push it
Even if improve it somewhat by replacing hardcoded multipliers with vGap accessors
        toolbar.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) toolbar.getLayout();
                JButton firstButton = (JButton) toolbar.getComponent(0);
                JButton secondButton = (JButton) toolbar.getComponent(1);
                double firstButtonY = firstButton.getLocation().getY();
                double secondButtonY = secondButton.getLocation().getY();
                if (firstButtonY < secondButtonY) {
                    int newHeight = firstButton.getHeight() + secondButton.getHeight() + flowLayout.getVgap() * 3;
                    toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, newHeight));
                } else if (firstButtonY == firstButtonY) {
                    int oldHeight = firstButton.getHeight() + flowLayout.getVgap() * 2;
                    toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, oldHeight));
                }
            }
        });

there's still the problem that it doesn't support more than two buttons. Again, I can write some loop but it gets too complex for something that is likely available OOB

The icons are included to determine a minimum size of a button. A button can shrink as much as possible (shrinking the text as JLabels do) but should always be wide enough to store its icon. I didn't write it in the question body so that it's not closed for being unfocused. It should likely be asked separately

Consider using new URI(resourceName).toURL(); in getButton() to make your [mre] easier to test.

Note that BorderLayout.NORTH "may be stretched horizontally" but it won't grow vertically; you may want to experiment with a different layout.

@trashgod do you suggest passing absolute paths? Putting the images in the resource root is pretty easy

@trashgod it does respect the preferred height of it north child as proved by my kludge (see the edit)

No, pass the URL of the image(s)you posted, for example; you may want to experiment with a different layout.

@trashgod if the toolbar doesn't ask for more vertical space, it doesn't seem to matter what layout its parent has

@trashgod for some reason https://i.sstatic.net/CnC7LVrk.png returns 403 when queried from java code (not from the browser): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: https://i.sstatic.net/CnC7LVrk.png. So, unfortunately, I can't introduce the change you ask for

but it won't grow vertically; you may want to experiment with a different layout.

Instead of using the FlowLayout check out the Wrap Layout.


@camickr again, what difference would it make if the toolbar itself doesn't ask for more space?

(1-) Because you don't understand how layout managers work. It is the layout manager that  determines how much space is needed to display all the components in the toolbar. I took the time to answer the question. Did you even take the time to follow the link and try the code? Do you have a question about the explanation in the link as to why the WrapLayout should solve your problem? It works for me based on your MRE, or I don't understand the question.

@camickr why would the layout manager of the header panel's parent allocate it more vertical space? How would it know the contained toolbar stacked its children and needs that space? The toolbar's fine with its original height, no matter whether its children wrap or not

why would the layout manager of the header panel's parent allocate it more vertical space? - because it asks all the child components in the panel for their preferred sizes. 1) Did you try the code? Does it do what you want or not? 2) What don't you understand about the explanation for the creation of the WrapLayout class?

trashgod is right;  the edges of a BorderLayout will accommodate the initial preferred size of their component, but will never grow toward the center.  That’s just how BorderLayout works.  Of course, you can call headerPanel.revalidate() each time mainPanelLayout is resized.

@VGR, There is no need to specifically invoke revalidate() on the panel. This happens automatically as the frame is resized. That is, the layout managers of the panels are invoked so the current preferred size can be calculated.

@VGR but my solution seems to suggest otherwise. The new preferred height is respected, the north component does get the extra space it asks for

@camickr while the WrapLayout seems to do the trick (thank you for you suggestion, I encourage you to post), I'm not sure we can just incorporate a class of some random blogger on the Internet. It's not even a Maven Central artifact. I admire the author's creativeness and don't imply he or she did a bad job


The random blogger is me. 2) On the "About" and "Contact Us" pages of the blog it states you can use the code. 3) On the github site the license is also listed if you click on the "tips4java" part of "tips4java/source/WrapLayout" you will find the license. I gave my best effort to indicate that the code can be freely used.


@camickr if so, why did you declare the preferredLayoutSize (a private unused field)?

I removed some logic as part of a bug fix and forgot to remove the variable.

It seems, it's not possible OOB
The goal can be achieved by adding a component listener to the toolbar (or using a custom layout, but I'll let camickr post it if they wish)
Notice the listener code assumes the toolbar has the FlowLayout set. Otherwise, it won't work
It's also important that the preferred height of the toolbar is respected by its parent's layout manager
        toolbar.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Component[] components = toolbar.getComponents();
                if (components.length < 1) return;
                FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) toolbar.getLayout();
                int preferredHeight = flowLayout.getVgap() + components[0].getHeight();
                Component previousComponent = components[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < components.length; i++) {
                    Component currentComponent = components[i];
                    double previousComponentY = previousComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    double currentComponentY = currentComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    if (previousComponentY < currentComponentY) {
                        preferredHeight += flowLayout.getVgap() + currentComponent.getHeight();
                    }
                    previousComponent = currentComponent;
                }
                preferredHeight += flowLayout.getVgap();
                toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, preferredHeight));
            }
        });

The full code:
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Objects;

public class FlowToolbarDemo {
    /*
     some components are made fields to make them accessible in the IntelliJ debugger
     when breakpoints are placed in the buttons' ActionListeners
    */
    static JPanel headerPanel;
    static JToolBar toolbar;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Flow Toolbar Demo");
        JPanel labelPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Click to see action");
        label.setOpaque(true);
        label.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        labelPanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        toolbar = new JToolBar();
        LayoutManager toolbarLayout = new FlowLayout();
        toolbar.setLayout(toolbarLayout);
        JButton heartButton = getHeartButton();
        JButton starButton = getStarButton();
        toolbar.add(heartButton);
        toolbar.add(starButton);

        LayoutManager headerPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        headerPanel = new JPanel(headerPanelLayout);
        headerPanel.add(labelPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        headerPanel.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        JPanel businessPanel = getBusinessPanel();

        LayoutManager mainPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(mainPanelLayout);
        mainPanel.add(headerPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        mainPanel.add(businessPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        heartButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            label.setText("Heart action performed...");
        });

        starButton.addActionListener(e -> {
            label.setText("Star action performed...");
        });

        toolbar.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Component[] components = toolbar.getComponents();
                if (components.length < 1) return;
                FlowLayout flowLayout = (FlowLayout) toolbar.getLayout();
                int preferredHeight = flowLayout.getVgap() + components[0].getHeight();
                Component previousComponent = components[0];
                for (int i = 1; i < components.length; i++) {
                    Component currentComponent = components[i];
                    double previousComponentY = previousComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    double currentComponentY = currentComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    if (previousComponentY < currentComponentY) {
                        preferredHeight += flowLayout.getVgap() + currentComponent.getHeight();
                    }
                    previousComponent = currentComponent;
                }
                preferredHeight += flowLayout.getVgap();
                toolbar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(toolbar.getPreferredSize().width, preferredHeight));
            }
        });

        frame.setContentPane(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static JPanel getBusinessPanel() {
        LayoutManager businessPanelLayout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel businessPanel = new JPanel(businessPanelLayout);
        JTable tableOne = getTableOne();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneOne = new JScrollPane(tableOne);
        scrollPaneOne.setOpaque(true);
        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
        tabbedPane.addTab("Business Table One", scrollPaneOne);
        JTable tableTwo = getTableTwo();
        JScrollPane scrollPaneTwo = new JScrollPane(tableTwo);
        scrollPaneTwo.setOpaque(true);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Business Table Two", scrollPaneTwo);
        businessPanel.add(tabbedPane);
        return businessPanel;
    }

    private static JTable getTableOne() {
        Object[][] data = {
                {"John Doe", 30, "Male"},
                {"Jane Smith", 25, "Female"},
                {"Alice Johnson", 35, "Female"}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Name", "Age", "Gender"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        return new JTable(model);
    }

    private static JTable getTableTwo() {
        Object[][] data = {
                {"Apple", 30, true},
                {"Orange", 25, true},
                {"Ackee fruit", 35, false}
        };
        String[] columns = {"Fruit", "Quantity", "Is Edible"};
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns);
        return new JTable(model);
    }

    private static JButton getHeartButton() throws IOException {
        return getButton("Do Heart action", "heart.png");
    }

    private static JButton getStarButton() throws IOException {
        return getButton("Do Star action", "star.png");
    }

    private static JButton getButton(String buttonText, String resourceName) throws IOException {
        URL imageLocation = FlowToolbarDemo.class.getResource(resourceName);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Objects.requireNonNull(imageLocation, "Requested resource not found"));
        Image scaledImage = image.getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(scaledImage);
        JButton button = new JButton(buttonText, icon);
        button.setFocusPainted(false);
        return button;
    }
}

Here's what it does. Note I only shrink it horizontally and never allocate it more vertical space myself


Limitations
The shortcomings of the solution (and, come to think of it, shortcomings of the solution involving WrapLayout) become apparent once you add a separator
        toolbar.add(heartButton);
        JToolBar.Separator separator = new JToolBar.Separator(new Dimension(2, heartButton.getPreferredSize().height));
        separator.setOpaque(true);
        separator.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        toolbar.add(separator);
        toolbar.add(starButton);

If you shrink far enough, you get this

I could make the separator disappear if it's the only component in row. However, I couldn't yet make it reappear once I make the window wide enough. See the commented out lines, they create a conflict between setVisible(true) and setVisible(false) calls
                    Component currentComponent = components[i];
                    double previousComponentY = previousComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    double currentComponentY = currentComponent.getLocation().getY();
                    if (currentComponent instanceof JSeparator) {
                        double nextComponentY = components[i + 1].getLocation().getY();
                        boolean isOnlyInRow = currentComponentY > previousComponentY && currentComponentY < nextComponentY;
                        if (isOnlyInRow) currentComponent.setVisible(false);
//                        else {
//                            currentComponent.setVisible(true);
//                            previousComponent = currentComponent;
//                        }
                        continue;
                    }


Your logic assumes the height of all components are the same. since you only set the preferred height for the first component with a different "y" value. If you want to make this assumption then there is no need for the loop. Just get the last component in the container. The preferred height would then be its "Y" value plus its height plus the vertical gap. This is way a layout solution is the better approach. Swing layout is based on using layout managers. If you don't want to use the WrapLayout then write your own and don't try so use the ComponentListener.

you only set the preferred height for the first component with a different "y" value I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I add each component's height (plus insets) to the overall preferred height in a loop. They could easily be different for different components

Didn't test, only a visual look at the code. It seems to me the previousComponentY will only be less than the currentComponentY once since you reset the previousComponentY. So only the first component in the row will be used to calculate the height increase. So if the second component in the row has a greater preferred height it won't be used in the calculation.
